# jdk change to 1.8_04, rcp application crash when use javafx

Tags: javafx, java-8, rcp

Before my rcp application still use jdk7, every thing is fine, but when change to jdk8, execute a javafx class, the application directly crash.
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000704d6e04, pid=14276, tid=13684
try to add -Dorg.osgi.framework.bundle.parent=ext in application.ini, it is not useful.
do you know why?

```
 Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.initIDs()
    ....
    javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas.initFx()
    j  javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas.init(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)
```

Comment: You could try a newer build of Java 8 - 1.8_60 is the current release.

Comment: 1.8_60 has the same problem.